# ELKI ClusteringVectorDumper - which ones are the outliers?

Tags: cluster-analysis, elki

I am using ELKI for DBSCAN clustering and its ClusteringVectorDumper to output the cluster ids into a text file.

Which id do outliers get? 
I assumed it was '0' but that does not seem to be true.

Comment: Noise is not the same as outliers. Cluster numbers are meaningless, like random numbers. And have you looked at the source code for your actual problem?

Comment: This doesn't answer my question...do you mean to tell me that outliers get one random id? or does every outlier have its own id?

Comment: It's a comment, not an answer. I'm saying that clusters don't "naturally" have an integer, so it's hard to predict what integer is assigned. I have used ELKI (but not that dumper); so I know it doesn't use one cluster per noise, but that all noise will be assigned the same cluster. But in hierarchical clustering, a point may be in multiple clusters. In Java, the clusters would have an `isNoise()` method on the cluster. No idea what the dumper does - have you checked the source?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the source code of [ClusteringVectorDumper](https://github.com/elki-project/elki/blob/master/elki/src/main/java/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/result/ClusteringVectorDumper.java#L182) online.

There is no special treatment of noise clusters, but they will be processed as returned by `Clustering.getAllClusters()`. To provide some stability, this method currently sorts by *name*. DBSCAN does not provide further cluster names (some algorithms do assign e.g. interval names, or subspace names), so if I recall correctly, all clusters will be named either `"Cluster"` or `"Noise"`. Because `"Noise"` sorts after `"Cluster"`, the *largest* index should be the noise cluster.

Feel free to send a pull request to improve either the naming, or the output. I had been considering to use negative numbers for noise clusters, but it would increase the code complexity; and people would likely not expect to see a cluster `-1` either.

It does not work well to abuse DBSCAN for outlier detection. It will miss outliers because they are reachable, and it will assign low-density clusters as outliers that other methods will easily recognize correctly. It also does not provide a ranking, so you have little control over how many outliers you get. If you would modify DBSCAN to provide such a ranking, you would likely reinvent one of the oldest outlier detection method, kNN outlier detection. (DB-Outlier is also very closely related to DBSCAN).

Comment: Cannot confirm this. Repeatedly tested the mouse.csv data set with DBSCAN, set the parameters so that most points were noise, then checked the clustering vector output and the index of the biggest cluster (= the noise) was often not 0 nor the last index.
I'll have to add that I am working on an old commit from Apr 13 (03fbea9028ceda5839b61b65cae647e029eb8f70), so it may be possible that this behaviour has changed.

Comment: Then you will have to come up with a logic that you like, and modify the code as desired.

Comment: As an ugly hack, you could prepend a data point that is at infinity to your data set. It will be noise; and then the first entry in the data file will indicate the noise class. (Untested, I would simply make a result handler exactly as I need it.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I do not intend to write this myself, but just as a suggestion if you want to implement something in the future, I would expect the noise cluster to be either 0 or -1 and I imagine it would seem intuitive to most people.

Comment: We have methods with more than one noise cluster. So that rule won't generally work. And -1 will surprise other users, as it means you can't use the value for array indexing. There is no solution that will make everybody happy, you'll have to customize.